# Why is the line end character not included in the char*?

Tags: c++, char, c-strings

Function TrimRight takes a line and removes all spaces at the end.

```
void TrimRight(char *s) // input "somestring   " (3 spaces at the end)
{
    // Here s == "somestring   \0" and strlen(s) == 14
    int last = strlen(s) - 2;
    std::cout << "Last1: " << s[last] << std::endl; // Last == ' '
    while (s[last] == ' ')
    {
        --last;
    }
    std::cout << "Last2: " << s[last] << std::endl;  // Last == 'g'
    s[last + 1] = '\0';
    // Here s == "somestring" and strlen(s) == 10
}
```

Questions is why s!= "somestring/0" after TrimRight(s)?
I'm using MVS 2017. Thanks.

Comment: If `s` is `"somestring   "` (with 3 spaces), then `strlen(s)` is not 14.

Comment: The string terminator character (`'\0'`) is not counted by `strlen()`.

Comment: Your function is broken on strings longer than `INT_MAX+2`, strings shorter than 2, and strings consisting of spaces only. It also produces wrong results if the last character in the string is not a space.

Comment: C++ has a string class, use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You thought after `TrimRight(s)`, s become `something\0`.

But in  `TrimRight(s)` function, `while loop` just passed from last index.

Pass mean it didn't delete `whitespace` and `\0`.

so s is not `something\0`. It is `something\0  \0` because of  "just pass".

[image]